# JtextField obtener un texto

Tags: java, java-swing

estoy haciendo una aplicación en la cual tengo aproximadamente unos 75  JTextField.

lo que quiero hacer es comprobar si el usuario introdujo cierto texto de haber introducido el texto ocurre algunas cosas.

lo realice de esta forma

```
String A1 = txt1.getText()
.
.
.
String A75 = txt75.getText()
```

y luego realizar la comparación con un if

```
if("Texto Deseado".equals(A1) || "Texto Deseado".equals(A2) ... || "Texto Deseado".equals(A75)
```

Que sucede es muy extensa la programaccion porque además la comparacion debo realizarla 20 veces mas porque tengo 20  posibles casos que puedan ocurrir dependiendo de dopnde se encuentre el **texto deseado**

¿Hay alguna forma de reducir este codigo, no se aplicando un for o algun while?

Quiero es algo que me reduzca el codigo!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar estructuras repetitivas. Ya que conoces la cantidad de repeticiones podrías utilizar la estructura repetitiva for.

Primero debes declarar una lista de String's.

```
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
```

Luego agregar los valores a la lista para su posterior uso;

```
lista.add(txt1.getText());
.
.
lista.add(txt75.getText());
```

Ahora recorremos el arreglo con los valores que le pasamos.

Iniciamos i en 0 ya que los arreglos no empiezan a contar desde 1 sino desde 0.

Luego ingresamos la condición a evaluar por repetición (esto te sirve para darle un alcance) i < 75

Por último especificas que es lo ocurrirá en cada vuelta: i++ (aumentarás el contador en 1, Por ejemplo: La primera vez valdrá 0, después 1, luego 2 y así sucesivamente hasta llegar a 75 [La condición que le pusimos, repetirá solo cuando i sea menor a 75. Y como 75 no es menor a 75 entonces termina la estructura repetitiva])

```
//Empiezas desde 1 y terminas cuando no sea menor a 75 
for(int i=0; i<75; i++) (total: 75 repeticiones)
{
   //Aquí evaluarás el valor de cada String que almacenaste
   if("Texto Deseado".equals(lista.get(i))
   {
        ...........
        ...........
        Aquí va tu código
        ...........
        ...........
   }
}
```